# django trying to put a table in a view

Tags: django

in my views.py:

```
def show(request):
    query_results=Emails.objects.all()

    #from py_utils import open_py_shell;open_py_shell.open_py_shell()

    context = { 'query_result' : query_results }
    return render(request, 'show.html', context)
```

in show.html:

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        {% for item in query_result %}
        <tr>
            <td>Ohad</td>
            <td>{{ item.email }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.baseurl }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

an email object has email field and baseurl field but it seems that i cannot load it,
i checked and in `query_result` i have a list of Emails object just cannot put it in the table, any help?

Comment: In the context, you have 'query_result', however in the template you iterate over query_results. You should iterate over the key, not over the value.

Comment: i tried it and still it didnt work

Comment: How did you check that query_result have any result?

Comment: from py_utils import open_py_shell;open_py_shell.open_py_shell(), 
open the shell in this status and i access query_results fileds

Comment: Other then that it looks ok. Install django debug toolbar, it is very useful to see relevant things about a request, like the context used to populate the template.